# JAX-RS: Service Resource order

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

currect state: 
1. in my web.xml:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

2. I have two service resources, with the same @Path

```
@Path("path")
public class Resource1 {
  //methods annotated with @Path
}

@Path("path")
public class SubResource extends Resource1 {
  //same methods annotated with @Path (are inherited, and not overridden)
}
```

Question. Is there a way to redirect all requests to "path" to the SubResource, and to the Resource1 ? In the current situation, it seems that the application server (JBoss in my case) decides by itself which resource to take, and it is not always the same.

Thank you.

Comment: The @Path("path") on both classes means there mapped on the same path?

Comment: Sounds like an architectural problem. There has to be a distinction between those two resources in the URI. You should at least wonder why you have to implement your methods two times.

Comment: @SatelliteSD, my explained it wrong: the methods are just inherited, nothing is reimplemented. Thanks, I corrected the Question/Code

Comment: @dcernahoschi , yes, they are mapped to the "same path". If you wonder where I need this: a library has a Resource Responsible for some requests, but in my application I want the same code, but with some additional requests.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've chosen is to use different @Path's. The SubResource has now a stronger Path, by having more literal characters:

```
@Path("path")
public class Resource1 {
  //methods annotated with @Path
}

@Path("/path")//NOTE that the leading slash makes the difference
public class SubResource extends Resource1 {
  //same methods annotated with @Path (are inherited, not overridden)
}
```

More on the the "Selection Algorithms" in JAX-RS [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-Overviewoftheselectionalgorithm).

Comment: It "seems" (not sure) that this is not part of the JAX-RS specification.